# How to access laravel eloquent relationship data using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I can easily access my relationship data from Laravel blade. However, whenever I try to access them from AJAX it shows undefined or error. I have tried all the way but can't solve it. Please help.

My Controllers Code:

```
 public function store(Request $request){

    $task_name = $request->task_name;
    $empId = $request->empName;
    $catId = $request->catName;
    $desName = $request->desName;
    $start = $request->start_date;
    $end = $request->end_date;

    $inputs = array();
    $task_start_date = Carbon::parse($start)->format('Y-m-d');
    $task_end_date = Carbon::parse($end)->format('Y-m-d');


    $inputs['name']= $task_name;
    $inputs['user_id']= $empId;
    $inputs['cat_id']= $catId;
    $inputs['des']= $desName;
    $inputs['start_date']= $task_start_date;
    $inputs['end_date']= $task_end_date;


    $tasks = Task::create($inputs);
    $table =  "";

    $items = Task::all();

    foreach ($items as $item){

        $table .=" <tr>";
        $table .=" <td>";
        $table .=$item->taskCategory->name;
        $table .=" </td>";
        $table .=" </tr>";
        $table .="";
    }

    $temps = Task::with('taskCategory')->get();

    return response()->json([
        $tasks,
        'table'=>$table,
        'temps'=>$temps

    ]);

}
```

My Eloquent Model Code:

```
 public function taskCategory(){

    return $this->belongsTo(TaskCategory::class,'cat_id','id');
}
```

My ajax code in laravel Blade:

```
 $(document).on('submit','#add_company_form', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:config.routes.task_post,
            method:"POST",
            data:new FormData(this),
            dataType:'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.id!=""){
                    // toastr.success('We do have the Kapua suite available.', 'Turtle Bay Resort', {timeOut: 5000})
                    //console.log(data);
                    toastr.options = {
                        "debug": false,
                        "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
                        "onclick": null,
                        "fadeIn": 300,
                        "fadeOut": 2000,
                        "timeOut": 2000,
                        "extendedTimeOut": 2000
                    };

                    var rowCount = $('#order-listing >tbody >tr').length+1;
                    $.each(data.temps, function (key, val) {

                        // console.log(val.taskCategory.name);
                        $('#companyappend').append(`<tr class="unqcompany` + val.id + `">


        <td>` + rowCount + `</td>
        <td>` + val.taskCategory.name+ ` </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary companyshow commonbtn" data-id="` + val.id + `" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_company_modal"><i class="ti-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success editcompany commonbtn" data-companyname="` + val.name + `"  data-id="` + val.id + `" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-icon-text deletecompany commonbtn"  data-id="` + val.id + `">
            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>`);
                    });
                    toastr.success('Task was Created successfully');
                    $('#add_company_form').trigger('reset');
                    // console.log(data.table);
                    // $('#companyappend').html(data.table);
                }else{
                    alert("Failed to store");
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

This is to say that I can access my relationship data from blade easily. But in AJAX it throws an error or undefined. Please Help me.

Comment: Is `taskCategory` defined in the `$visible` array in your `Task` model? If not, than the relation is discarded when the `Task` is converted to an array during the conversion in the `json` response code.

Comment: Sir, this is not declared in $visible array.

This is my Task Model code:

class Task extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table= 'task_master';
    protected $fillable= ['name','user_id','cat_id','des','start_date','end_date'];

    public function taskCategory(){

        return $this->belongsTo(TaskCategory::class,'cat_id','id');
    }

}

Comment: That is my point: it is not declared in the `$visible` array, and therefore when the model is converted to an array, the `taskCategory` property is filtered out. You must understand that blade views are working on the backend, and working with the PHP code, and thus can work with the Eloquent relations, while the javascript is frontend, and can only work with the data the backend returns. But the `taskCategory` prop is simply not part of the data the backend returns.